# Function template specialization without templated argument

Tags: c++

Let's look on a template function which take void argument and returns void:

```
template<class T>
void f() {
    cout << "template" << endl;
}
```

Later we specialize this function:

```
template<>
void f<int> () {
    cout << "int" << endl;
}
template<>
void f<double> () {
    cout << "double" << endl;
}

int main() {
    f<int> ();
    f<double> ();
}
```

The question is why this compiles? We have three function with the same signature:
`void(void)`, and I expected that it should broke with multiple declaration?

Comment: "why this compiles" -  because its *valid* c++ code. You have two full and proper specializations. It sounds like you're confusing specializing with *overloading*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are explicitly stating which function to use. `f<int>()` can not map to `f<double>()` because of the difference in template argument; i.e. this is a completely unambiguous call.

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't it work?  Those are three different implementations, depending on the template parameter.  Each different value you use when instantiating a template creates a completely new copy of the entire templated thing.  So here you make three functions, they're all unique and it works fine.

By the way, the symbol name won't be just `f`, look up C++ name mangling.