# C++ class templates can be implicity specialized and instantiated without angle brackets?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, argument-dependent-lookup

This actually compiles and works, but it's unclear to me why.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class LikeA
{
    T m_val{};
    public:
    LikeA() = default;
    explicit LikeA(T iv): m_val(std::move(iv)) {}
    LikeA(LikeA<T> const &) = default;
    LikeA(LikeA<T> &&) noexcept = default;
    ~LikeA() noexcept = default;
    operator T const &() const { return m_val; }
    LikeA<T> &operator=(T nv) { m_val = std::move(nv); return *this; }
    LikeA<T> &operator=(LikeA<T> const &n) { m_val = n.m_val; return *this; }
    LikeA<T> &operator=(LikeA<T> &&n) { m_val = std::move(n.m_val); return *this; }
};

template <class T>
T f (LikeA<T> i)
{
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f(LikeA{3.1415927}) << '\n';  // No template argument? Not a syntax error?
    return 0;
}
```

I was previously calling `f` like `f(3.1415927)` before I let a lint checker talk me into making one of `LikeA`s constructors `explicit`.   After that, of course, it couldn't implicitly convert the constant to a `LikeA`.  If you just add braces (i.e. `f({3.1415927})` the compiler still doesn't know what to select.

In my full code the actual template argument is a lot more verbose, so just for grins I put the template name `LikeA` in front of the brace initializers, fully expecting a syntax error.

To my surprise, **it compiled and ran**.

Since this was MSVC, at first I though it was just Microsoft lulling me into a sense of false security.  But I tested it against several compilers (gcc, clang, zigcc) in Compiler Explorer, and it works on all of them.

How does C++ select the correct template specialization?  On the surface, argument-dependent lookup would seem to be the answer, but notice there are no angle brackets, and the template doesn't have a default argument. I definitely remember this being a syntax error at some point in the past.

([Function template specialization without templated argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742819/function-template-specialization-without-templated-argument) doesn't answer this because OP actually specifies the arguments).

[The cppreference on function template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) has a quick aside about omitting `<>` but this is a class template. The syntax [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) appears to require the angle brackets all the time.

Comment: ([spoiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction))

Comment: I think your lint checker may have led you down the primrose path regarding [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) in this case.  It's not *bad* advice, but it's just advice to take under advisement.  It seems to me that this is a case where `explicit` is undesirable.

Comment: @Eljay You may be right, but it has some value since it led me to this.

Comment: Since C++17, compiler can automatically deduce the argument type of a template by using _class template argument deduction (CTAD)_. You can skip defining the templates
arguments explicitly if the constructor is able to deduce all template parameters.

Comment: @Aamir Sounds like answer material.

Comment: Stephen Lavavej's talk on CTAD should answer all your questions (and a few you probably didn't think to ask)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-H-ut6j1BYU

Comment: Taking out the `explicit`, I could not get the `f(3.1415927)` to work.  Hmm.  Maybe more things had evolved in the code since that used to work.

Comment: @Eljay In the full code `f` is not a template. It expects a specific `LikeA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17, compiler can automatically deduce the argument type of a template by using class template argument deduction (CTAD). You can skip defining the templates arguments explicitly if the constructor is able to deduce all template parameters.

So you simply write

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector v{2, 4, 6, 8};      // same as std::vector<int>
    std::list   l{1., 3., 5.};      // same as std::list<double>
    std::pair   p{false, "hello"};  // same as std::pair<bool, const char *>
    
    std::cout << typeid(v).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(l).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(p).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Under MSVC, it produces the following output

```
class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >
class std::list<double,class std::allocator<double> >
struct std::pair<bool,char const * __ptr64>
```

Kindly refer [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for more details.